# Save duration with precision in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, duration

I want to save duration in Parse.com. What can be better way to do this: Using Number or using Date.
Duration can be in milliseconds or can be hours of may be days.

For example:

```
duration = 5 seconds
duration = 2 days
duration = 50 milliseconds
```

Comment: A `Date` is not a duration (the word itself has rather to be interpreted as calendar date, if you mean `java.util.Date` then it is a point on universal time axis). Please clarify what programming language you use.

Comment: I am using Swift programming language. I am creating an iOS app with Parse.com as backend.

Comment: The duration is what? What is the start and end?

Comment: I do not want to save start and end time. I only want to save duration. For example: If a runner takes 00:03:15.56 duration to complete 100m race. Here I want to save 00:03:15.56.